# disable certain keys if text input field exceeds X number of characters?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.licensetable :text').live('keydown', function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) && (event.keyCode != 8)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I only allow numbers. This works. But if i log

```
$(this).val().length
```

Its obviously "one step after". If i bind the keyup event, i get the correct number. But then i cant disable the keypress event. My goal is to disable the input after a certain amount of numbers has been entered. Hope you get the idea. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable the text input as in `disabled="disabled"` or just prevent the number of characters exceeding _x_, i.e. `maxlength`?

Comment: @jakeclarkson "just prevent the number of characters exceeding x, i.e. maxlength" :)

Comment: `<input type="text" maxlength="x" ... />` will limit the number of characters to _x_ :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply set the attribute [`maxlength='X'`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-maxlength-attribute) on the input field.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Zbq/)**.

Comment: Perfect, didnt know that this attribute existed i html. Only seen something similar on asp.net web controls :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could use the  [maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) attributes of the input field so that the user can't enter more characthers than those (hope i understood your question correctly)

Then if you want to disable the input when the maxlength is reached you can do:

```
$('input:text').live('keydown', function(event) {

    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) && (event.keyCode != 8)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    if (this.value.length == maxlength) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/2YmAG/

Comment: Exactly. This functionality is built into HTML, no need for javascript/jQuery here.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that when im using the keydown event, it registers after the keypress. So when there are 2 characters, i will get "1", when there are 3 i will get 2 etc..

Comment: `size` controls the visual size of the text box, not the number of characters that can be entered (the control will scroll its viewport and allow more than `size` characters).

Comment: @Jon taken size away from the answer and added the code to disable the input field when maxlength is reached